# WordPress configure multiple upload directories for different section in

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to configure multiple upload directories in WordPress? I want to be able to use the standard WordPress media uploader but upload to different folders based on what I am uploading. As per [WordPress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php), you can set a custom uploads folder, but that will put all uploaded files to that folder.

What I need to have different pages which handle uploads differently( upload to different folders). That is, when I am on `Upload page 1` I need to upload to `.../uploads1/` and when I am in `Upload page 2`, I need to be upload to `.../uploads2/`.

I know you can do it using custom forms and call `wp_handle_upload` but want to try use the already working uploader.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack to solve the problem. You can all `update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', false); //disable default wordpress: .../uploads/year/month`

and 
    update_option('upload_path', 'upload/path'); // to update the path to uploads.

then after uploding, reset wordpress defauld by:

```
update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', true);
```